# Tracking api/even changes between different microservice versions before deployment

Tags: microservices, devops, devops-services

I work devops for a fairly large company that is in process of transitioning to microservices. This is a new area for most people involved and some of the governing requests seem like bad practice to me but I don't have the expertise to convince otherwise.

The request is to generate a report before deploying that would list any new api/events (Kafka is our messaging service) in a microservice.

The path that's being recommended is for devs to follow a style guide and then scrape the source code during CI/CD pipeline to generate a report that can be compared to previous reports and identify any new apis.

This seems backwards and unsustainable but I've been unable to find another solution that would satisfy their requests. I've recommended deploying to dev first, then using a tracing tool to identify any api changes, or event subscriptions, but they insist on having the report before deploying.

I'm hoping for any advice on best practice to accomplish this.

Comment: You can make use of versioning apis, like whenever any new api is introduced increment the version number and that's how based on that number you will know what all endpoints were introduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tracing and detecting version changes is definitely over engineering. Whats simpler like @zenwraight has mentioned, is to version your APIs. While tracing through services to explore the different versions and schema could be a potential solution, it requires a lot more investment upfront and if thats not the bread and butter of the company, I would rather use a vendor product that might support something like this.

If discovery is a mechanism that is needed, I would recommend something that publishes internal API docs using a tool like Swagger so that you can search if there's an API you can consume.

And finally to support moving to different versions, I would recommend having an API onboarding process for the services so that teams can notify other teams that are using specific versions their services are coming to the end of their lifecycle and they will need to migrate to newer ones.